# How to store iterated column data in 2d array C++ programming

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have written a sample code to read value from DB ,I want to store the values in a structure and return that structure,
How to store data in array, I see at single instance I am not getting column data, column data is coming iteration by iteration so how to store in a **row[0]=100 Jeera GRIbbon** the continuous characters, **row[1] = 101 SAM  Abbbon**, **row[2]=**...

```
         int rc,cc,colType;
         char *empRec;
         char *colValue;

         for ( rc =0; rc<result.RowCount(); rc ++)
             {
               empRec = result[rc];

               for ( cc=0;cc<result.NumberOfColumns();cc++)
                  {
                    colValue = empRec + result.ColumnOffset(cc);
                    colType = result.ColumnType(cc);

                    switch(colType)
                        {
                        case RWDBValue::Decimal:
                                cout<<*(float *)colValue<<",";
                                break;
                        case RWDBValue::String:
                        case RWDBValue::Char:
                                cout<<*((char **)colValue)<<","<<"\n"<<endl;
                                break;
                        default:
                                cout<<"Get lost..."<<endl;
                                break;
                        }
                }
        cout<<endl;
```

```
Output:
100 Jeera   GRIbbon
101 SAM     Abbbon
102 Bali    Goutr
```

Comment: _How to store iterated column data in 2d array_, _I want to store the values in a structure_. Do you want to store it in a structure or a 2d array?

Comment: [ES.22: Don’t declare a variable until you have a value to initialize it with](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-init)

Comment: I want to store in 2d array

Comment: Do you know the array sizes at compile time?

Comment: Thanks but size is unknown.

Comment: Then you should use a [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of vectors. How do you want to store the different data types? You could use a void pointer. But it would be better to have a structure with necessary data types.